# Unable to do recording Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Im new to Jmeter . While doing the recording Im getting the below error . please help me

Error:

java.net.UnknownHostException: [www.gstatic.com](http://www.gstatic.com)

at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:939)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:650)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:66)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1301)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.run(Proxy.java:251)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like JMeter cannot access the Internet, most probably you're behind a corporate [proxy server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server)

If you want to record website(s) (or other resources) which are in the Internet - you need to make JMeter aware of the upstream proxy.

Normally your Internet connection looks like:

```
browser -> corporate proxy -> Internet
```

when you're recording with JMeter you substitute your corporate proxy with JMeter hence Internet access won't be available anymore:

```
browser -> JMeter proxy -> you can only access local resources
```

so you need to make it like:

```
browser -> JMeter proxy -> corporate proxy -> Internet
```

See [Using JMeter behind a proxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server) user manual chapter for more information.

---

Additionally I don't think you should be recording requests to `www.gstatic.com` as it's [Google's CDN](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/what-is-gstatic-com-used-for-all-you-need-to-know) so I believe you neither should record the calls to that site nor replay them as this is something absolutely beyond your control, moreover your IP address can get banned (unless you're a Google employee who has the task to load test the CDN). See [Web Testing with JMeter: How To Properly Handle Embedded Resources in HTML Responses](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter) article for more information if needed.

Comment: Thanks Sir I tried the option enable jmeter proxy --> corp proxy to connect internet but no luck. Do you have any other suggestion??

Comment: I already provided you the "other suggestion": don't record requests to `gstatic.com` unless you're a Google employee. If you are it's very sad that you are not capable of properly configuring proxy settings in the application. Alternatively you can consider [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium) for recording a test, in this case you don't have to worry about proxies and SSL certificates.